# R merge two dataframes with same columns without replacing values

Tags: r, sqldf

I have the following two columns:

e_2020_certified_Machines_Per_Jurisdiction_count_per_state:
[image]

And e_2016_certified_Machines_Per_Jurisdiction_count_per_state:

[image]

I would like to merge these two dataframes together so that it looks like this: (Sample data)

[image]

I have tried numerous things including:
1: Using the select function;
2: Merging the dataframes
3: Creating a new dataframe and inserting the data through the SQLDF package

I either get duplicated data, data that is overwritten or dataframes where 2020 gets replaced in its entirety by 2016 etc.

Help would be greatly appreciated. I've been at this for a few hours now.

I'm very sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find a question similar to this on stackoverflow which actually solved the problem.

If I manage to find the answer in the meantime I'll make sure to post it as well.

Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: Please post your data as copy/pasteable text, not as pictures.

Comment: It's hard to see from the images, but if you want to essentially "stack" one data frame on top of the other and they already have the same columns `rbind(data1, data2)`. Though if the rows are unique, then `merge(data1, data2, all = TRUE)` should work just as well.

Comment: @GregorThomas Your solution worked, THANK YOU! I didn't put all = TRUE at the end of the merge, that is why it didn't work.

Comment: You might want to read about [different types of joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) It will teach you standard language to talk about (and search for help) on problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Thanks to @GregorThomas for providing the answer.

This problem was solved with the following command:

```
merge(data1, data2, all = TRUE)
```